# Как добавить в трей иконку приложения?

Tags: wpf, .net

Я не нашел в списке компонентов WPF ничего, что позволило бы создать в трее иконку, а создавать ее вручную, вызовами Win API, - это большие хлопоты с PInvoke и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример создания [значка уведомления](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) c помощью компонента
[System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

В состав WPF NotifyIcon не входит, можно использовать [вот этот WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon).